# List all RPM packages installed from repo "X"

Tags: fedora, rhel, yum, rpm, dnf

How can I get a list of all of the RPM packages that have been installed on my system from a particular repo (e.g., "epel")?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

## Fedora 36 or later

```
dnf repository-packages epel list
```

## CentOS / RHEL / Fedora 22 or earlier

```
yum list installed | grep @epel
```

## Fedora 23

```
dnf list installed | grep @epel
```

## RHEL8

```
dnf repo-pkgs epel list installed
```

Comment: This will not work. Yum will output lines to the pipe that will be broken if they get too long. So grep's input is mostly one line per package, but it could be two lines. Yum could pass "whizbanger.x86_64 ___ 3.8.4-2.el6 _______________ @epel". (Imagine the underscores as spaces.) The "@epel" is on the next line of the input grep sees. So grep is going to output that line with nothing but "@epel" but not the preceding line with the package name.

Comment: You may need to run those commands as root until https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1525645 is fixed.

Comment: the yum command doesn't seem to work if one the repos is having issues.  i needed this list to see if i wanted to disable the repo with issues.

Comment: @Todd Watson I know, it is a hack, but what about "export COLUMNS=999 yum..."

Comment: Does that work, @Massimo? That would be a nice workaround. I found also this Unix StackExchange question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308731/how-to-remove-line-wrapping-from-dnf-yum-commands

Comment: sorry I am at home, not tested

Comment: First command should be `dnf repository-packages epel list --installed`, otherwise it lists all packages available in the repo.

Answer (score 24):

As of RHEL6, as suggested in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4934975/1980619), there's a more thorough method of doing this with `yumdb`:

```
yumdb search from_repo REPOID*
```

The repoid takes wild cards.

#### Pretty-print

If we're going to cheat and pipe the output, then we can achieve pretty-print effect as well.  Here's one using `awk`

```
yumdb search from_repo REPOID* |awk -F"\n" '{ RS=""; print $1 }'
```

Using `egrep` or `grep -e`

```
yumdb search from_repo REPOID* |egrep -v '(from_repo|^$)'
```

---

#### list_ALL_AVAILABLE_from_repo

To list **all *available* packages** in a specified repository, do:

```
repoquery -a --repoid=REPONAME
```

Comment: Just a side-note: To list all packages from a specified repo, do `repoquery -qa --repoid=REPONAME`

Comment: This is also a great answer. The output is longer than the accepted answer, but it's formatted in a nicer way.

Comment: Can be simplified to `repoquery -a --repoid=REPONAME` because according to man page `-q` option is *for rpmquery compatibility, doesn't do anything.*

Comment: @Rockallite is right; for dnf, the `-qa` actually fails.  I can't upvote the comment due to previously removing the upvote :(  I'm updating the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work well if packages have been installed using dnf as yum just lists those as 'installed' and doesn't specify the repo they came from. If you have installed packages via dnf the answer from @Peque will work properly

Answer (score 22):

```
dnf repo-pkgs <repoid> list installed
```

---

### Notes

The command above uses [DNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNF_(software)) to list the packages installed from the `<repoid>`. Note `repo-pkgs` is just an alias of `repository-packages`.

From the `man` pages:

```
man dnf | grep "repository-packages.*list.*installed" -A 1
```

Further reading:

```
man dnf
```

Comment: Best answer, works also with RHEL 7.7 `yum`. answers grepping for repo ID fails because sometimes tabulation causes packages and repos to go on different lines. This one is solid though.

Answer (score 4):

Grepping yum's output is the most obvious way:

```
yum list installed | grep @epel
```

However, you can't display extra packages properties and it's difficult to parse with a script. The tool `repoquery` from the package `yum-utils` is the tool, but it isn't installed by default.

```
repoquery -a --installed --qf "%{ui_from_repo} %{name}" | grep '^@epel'
```

and a more complex example:

```
repoquery -a --installed --qf "%-20{ui_from_repo} %-30{name} %-7{arch} %{epoch}:%-12{version} %-4{release}" | grep '^@epel'
```

Answer (score 3):

### RHEL Server 7.5 (Maipo)

`yum repo-pkgs <repoid> list installed` can be used to retrieve the same info as `yumdb search from_repo <repoid>`, but in a different format.

```
# yum help repo-pkgs
repo-pkgs <repoid> <list|info|install|remove|upgrade|reinstall*|remove-or-*> [pkg(s)]

Treat a repo. as a group of packages, so we can install/remove all of them

aliases: repo-packages, repository-pkgs, repository-packages
```

Sample `epel` outputs:

```
# yumdb search from_repo epel
htop-2.2.0-1.el7.x86_64
    from_repo = epel

supervisor-3.1.4-1.el7.noarch
    from_repo = epel


# yum repo-pkgs epel list installed
Installed Packages
htop.x86_64            2.2.0-1.el7          @epel
supervisor.noarch      3.1.4-1.el7          @epel
```

Answer (score 2):

You could check the `Vendor` header of installed rpms.

This example lists all package from *VideoLAN* repository:

```
 rpm -q -a --qf "%{Name}:%{Vendor}\n" \
     | grep -F ":VideoLAN Project (http://www.videolan.org)"
```

Obviously, you need to determine if the `Vendor` header of your repository is unique among different repositories.

Comment: There isn't a one-to-one mapping between Vendor and repos, and in some cases, the Vendor string is blank.

Answer (score 1):

For people who just want to find missing repositories:

```
yum list installed | awk '{print $3}' | sort | uniq
```

This should return all repositories where you have packages installed from.

Answer (score 0):

For RHEL 8:

```
dnf repository-packages epel list
```

Comment: Could you say something about what this does that none of the other answers already accomplishes?