# Getting conflict errors when running yum update

Tags: yum, upgrade

I'm truing to run yum update, and keep getting errors about conflicts. I must have accidentally interrupted an update at some point, but I don't know when and how.

I've tried —skip-broken, but it doesn't really help me, because I want to update the parts that now refuse to update.

Also, I've tried "yum remove util-linux", but then when I tried to re-install it, it didn't let me. Due to conflict errors much like what I'm getting now. (So I reverted to a backup volume, hence back on square 1).

Any ideas of how I can solve this?

```
yum update
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                                                                                                                                                   | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates/latest                                                                                                                                                                | 2.3 kB     00:00     
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package aws-amitools-ec2.noarch 0:1.5.2-0.0.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package aws-amitools-ec2.noarch 0:1.5.3-0.0.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package aws-apitools-as.noarch 0:1.0.61.4-1.0.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package aws-apitools-as.noarch 0:1.0.61.5-1.0.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package aws-apitools-ec2.noarch 0:1.6.13.0-1.1.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package aws-apitools-ec2.noarch 0:1.7.1.0-1.2.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package aws-apitools-elb.noarch 0:1.0.34.0-1.0.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package aws-apitools-elb.noarch 0:1.0.35.0-1.0.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package aws-cli.noarch 0:1.3.6-1.0.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package aws-cli.noarch 0:1.3.24-1.0.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package cloud-init.noarch 0:0.5.15-77.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package cloud-init.noarch 0:0.7.2-7.20.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package cloud-init.noarch 0:0.7.2-7.27.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package curl.x86_64 0:7.35.0-2.42.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package curl.x86_64 0:7.36.0-2.44.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package curl.x86_64 0:7.36.0-2.45.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package cyrus-sasl.x86_64 0:2.1.23-13.13.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package cyrus-sasl.x86_64 0:2.1.23-13.15.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package cyrus-sasl-lib.x86_64 0:2.1.23-13.10.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package cyrus-sasl-lib.x86_64 0:2.1.23-13.13.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package cyrus-sasl-lib.x86_64 0:2.1.23-13.15.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package cyrus-sasl-plain.x86_64 0:2.1.23-13.10.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package cyrus-sasl-plain.x86_64 0:2.1.23-13.13.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package cyrus-sasl-plain.x86_64 0:2.1.23-13.15.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package ec2-net-utils.noarch 0:0.4-1.20.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package ec2-net-utils.noarch 0:0.4-1.22.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package ec2-utils.noarch 0:0.4-1.20.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package ec2-utils.noarch 0:0.4-1.22.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package elfutils-libelf.x86_64 0:0.152-1.12.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package elfutils-libelf.x86_64 0:0.157-2.14.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package elfutils-libelf.x86_64 0:0.158-3.16.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package file.x86_64 0:5.11-13.14.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package file.x86_64 0:5.11-13.16.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package file.x86_64 0:5.19-1.18.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package file-libs.x86_64 0:5.11-13.14.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package file-libs.x86_64 0:5.11-13.16.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package file-libs.x86_64 0:5.19-1.18.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.12-1.132.45.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.17-36.81.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.17-55.84.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.12-1.132.45.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.17-36.81.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.17-55.84.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package glibc-devel.x86_64 0:2.17-36.81.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package glibc-devel.x86_64 0:2.17-55.84.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.17-36.81.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.17-55.84.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package gnupg2.x86_64 0:2.0.22-1.24.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package gnupg2.x86_64 0:2.0.24-1.25.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package httpd.x86_64 0:2.2.27-1.2.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package httpd.x86_64 0:2.2.27-1.3.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package httpd-tools.x86_64 0:2.2.27-1.2.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package httpd-tools.x86_64 0:2.2.27-1.3.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64 1:1.6.0.0-66.1.13.1.62.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64 1:1.6.0.0-66.1.13.1.63.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64 1:1.6.0.0-67.1.13.4.65.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:3.10.48-55.140.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:3.10.35-43.137.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:3.10.48-55.140.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package libblkid.x86_64 0:2.17.2-13.17.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package libblkid.x86_64 0:2.23.2-6.21.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package libblkid.x86_64 0:2.23.2-16.22.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package libcurl.x86_64 0:7.35.0-2.42.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package libcurl.x86_64 0:7.36.0-2.44.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package libcurl.x86_64 0:7.36.0-2.45.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package libmount.x86_64 0:2.23.2-6.21.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package libmount.x86_64 0:2.23.2-16.22.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package libpwquality.x86_64 0:1.2.3-1.2.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package libpwquality.x86_64 0:1.2.3-1.5.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package libtasn1.x86_64 0:2.3-3.4.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package libtasn1.x86_64 0:2.3-6.6.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package libuuid.x86_64 0:2.17.2-13.17.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package libuuid.x86_64 0:2.23.2-6.21.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package libuuid.x86_64 0:2.23.2-16.22.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package libxml2.x86_64 0:2.9.1-1.1.28.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package libxml2.x86_64 0:2.9.1-1.1.29.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package libxml2.x86_64 0:2.9.1-1.1.31.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package mod_ssl.x86_64 1:2.2.27-1.2.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package mod_ssl.x86_64 1:2.2.27-1.3.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package mysql55.x86_64 0:5.5.34-1.40.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package mysql55.x86_64 0:5.5.36-1.44.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package mysql55.x86_64 0:5.5.38-1.0.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package mysql55-common.x86_64 0:5.5.34-1.40.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package mysql55-common.x86_64 0:5.5.36-1.44.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package mysql55-common.x86_64 0:5.5.38-1.0.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package mysql55-libs.x86_64 0:5.5.34-1.40.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package mysql55-libs.x86_64 0:5.5.36-1.44.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package mysql55-libs.x86_64 0:5.5.38-1.0.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package mysql55-server.x86_64 0:5.5.34-1.40.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package mysql55-server.x86_64 0:5.5.36-1.44.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package mysql55-server.x86_64 0:5.5.38-1.0.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package nspr.x86_64 0:4.10.2-1.19.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package nspr.x86_64 0:4.10.4-1.22.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package nss.x86_64 0:3.15.3-3.32.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package nss.x86_64 0:3.16.0-1.36.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package nss-softokn.x86_64 0:3.14.3-9.15.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package nss-softokn.x86_64 0:3.16.0-1.19.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package nss-softokn-freebl.x86_64 0:3.14.3-9.15.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package nss-softokn-freebl.x86_64 0:3.16.0-1.19.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package nss-sysinit.x86_64 0:3.15.3-3.32.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package nss-sysinit.x86_64 0:3.16.0-1.36.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package nss-tools.x86_64 0:3.15.3-3.32.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package nss-tools.x86_64 0:3.16.0-1.36.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package nss-util.x86_64 0:3.15.3-1.18.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package nss-util.x86_64 0:3.15.3-1.19.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package nss-util.x86_64 0:3.16.0-1.22.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package openssh.x86_64 0:6.2p2-7.40.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package openssh.x86_64 0:6.2p2-8.41.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package openssh-clients.x86_64 0:6.2p2-7.40.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package openssh-clients.x86_64 0:6.2p2-8.41.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package openssh-server.x86_64 0:6.2p2-7.40.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package openssh-server.x86_64 0:6.2p2-8.41.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-4.55.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.1g-1.69.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.1i-1.78.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package pam.x86_64 0:1.1.1-13.20.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package pam.x86_64 0:1.1.8-1.25.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package pam.x86_64 0:1.1.8-9.29.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package python-boto.noarch 0:2.27.0-1.0.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package python-boto.noarch 0:2.32.0-1.0.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package python-botocore.noarch 0:0.40.0-1.0.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package python-botocore.noarch 0:0.58.0-1.0.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package python-jmespath.noarch 0:0.3.1-1.0.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package python-jmespath.noarch 0:0.4.1-1.0.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package python-simplejson.x86_64 0:3.3.0-1.5.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package python-simplejson.x86_64 0:3.5.3-1.7.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package readline.x86_64 0:6.0-4.12.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package readline.x86_64 0:6.2-6.13.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package readline.x86_64 0:6.2-9.14.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package util-linux.x86_64 0:2.23.2-6.21.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package util-linux.x86_64 0:2.23.2-16.22.amzn1 will be obsoleting
---> Package util-linux-ng.x86_64 0:2.17.2-13.17.amzn1 will be obsoleted
--> Processing Conflict: glibc-2.17-55.84.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts audit < 2.3.0
--> Processing Conflict: util-linux-2.23.2-16.22.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts coreutils < 8.20
--> Processing Conflict: util-linux-2.23.2-16.22.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts sysvinit < 2.87-5
--> Processing Conflict: util-linux-2.23.2-16.22.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts sysvinit < 2.87-5
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.17-36.81.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.17-36.81.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:3.4.76-65.111.amzn1 will be erased
--> Processing Conflict: glibc-2.17-55.84.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts audit < 2.3.0
--> Processing Conflict: util-linux-2.23.2-16.22.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts coreutils < 8.20
--> Processing Conflict: util-linux-2.23.2-16.22.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts sysvinit < 2.87-5
--> Processing Conflict: util-linux-2.23.2-16.22.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts sysvinit < 2.87-5
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: util-linux conflicts with coreutils-8.4-31.20.amzn1.x86_64
Error: util-linux conflicts with sysvinit-2.87-4.dsf.10.amzn1.x86_64
Error: util-linux conflicts with upstart-0.6.5-12.10.amzn1.x86_64
Error: glibc conflicts with audit-2.2-2.17.amzn1.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 113 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
apr-1.5.0-2.11.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with apr-1.4.6-1.10.amzn1.x86_64
audit-2.3.2-3.19.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with audit-2.2-2.17.amzn1.x86_64
audit-libs-2.3.2-3.19.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with audit-libs-2.2-2.17.amzn1.x86_64
ca-certificates-2013.1.94-65.0.9.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with ca-certificates-2012.1.95-3.12.amzn1.noarch
cloud-init-0.7.2-7.20.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with cloud-init-0.5.15-77.amzn1.noarch
coreutils-8.21-13.31.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with coreutils-8.4-31.20.amzn1.x86_64
cronie-anacron-1.4.4-7.5.amzn1.x86_64 has missing requires of cronie = ('0', '1.4.4', '7.5.amzn1')
cronie-anacron-1.4.4-12.6.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with cronie-anacron-1.4.4-7.5.amzn1.x86_64
cryptsetup-1.6.2-2.11.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with cryptsetup-1.5.1-1.3.amzn1.x86_64
cryptsetup-libs-1.6.2-2.11.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with cryptsetup-libs-1.5.1-1.3.amzn1.x86_64
curl-7.36.0-2.44.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with curl-7.35.0-2.42.amzn1.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.23-13.13.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.23-13.10.amzn1.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-plain-2.1.23-13.13.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with cyrus-sasl-plain-2.1.23-13.10.amzn1.x86_64
db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with db4-4.7.25-17.10.amzn1.x86_64
db4-utils-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with db4-utils-4.7.25-17.10.amzn1.x86_64
1:dbus-1.6.12-5.25.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:dbus-1.2.24-7.16.amzn1.x86_64
1:dbus-libs-1.6.12-5.25.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:dbus-libs-1.2.24-7.16.amzn1.x86_64
dejavu-fonts-common-2.33-5.8.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with dejavu-fonts-common-2.30-2.4.amzn1.noarch
dejavu-sans-fonts-2.33-5.8.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with dejavu-sans-fonts-2.30-2.4.amzn1.noarch
dejavu-serif-fonts-2.33-5.8.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with dejavu-serif-fonts-2.30-2.4.amzn1.noarch
12:dhclient-4.1.1-38.P1.19.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with 12:dhclient-4.1.1-34.P1.18.amzn1.x86_64
12:dhcp-common-4.1.1-38.P1.19.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with 12:dhcp-common-4.1.1-34.P1.18.amzn1.x86_64
e2fsprogs-libs-1.42.8-2.29.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with e2fsprogs-libs-1.42.3-3.17.amzn1.x86_64
elfutils-libelf-0.157-2.14.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with elfutils-libelf-0.152-1.12.amzn1.x86_64
file-5.11-13.16.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with file-5.11-13.14.amzn1.x86_64
file-libs-5.11-13.16.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with file-libs-5.11-13.14.amzn1.x86_64
glib2-2.36.3-2.14.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with glib2-2.22.5-7.11.amzn1.x86_64
glibc-2.17-36.81.amzn1.x86_64 has installed conflicts audit < ('0', '2.3.0', None): audit-2.2-2.17.amzn1.x86_64
glibc-2.17-36.81.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with glibc-2.12-1.132.45.amzn1.x86_64
glibc-common-2.17-36.81.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with glibc-common-2.12-1.132.45.amzn1.x86_64
groff-1.22.2-6.10.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with groff-1.18.1.4-21.7.amzn1.x86_64
groff-base-1.22.2-6.10.amzn1.x86_64 has installed conflicts groff < ('0', '1.22.2', None): groff-1.18.1.4-21.7.amzn1.x86_64
grubby-7.0.15-5.7.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with grubby-7.0.15-3.6.amzn1.x86_64
gzip-1.5-4.16.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with gzip-1.3.12-19.9.amzn1.x86_64
hwdata-0.233-9.1.16.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with hwdata-0.233-7.9.14.amzn1.noarch
info-5.1-1.9.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with info-4.13a-8.8.amzn1.x86_64
initscripts-9.03.40-2.29.amzn1.x86_64 has installed conflicts util-linux-ng < ('0', '2.23', None): util-linux-ng-2.17.2-13.17.amzn1.x86_64
initscripts-9.03.40-2.29.amzn1.x86_64 has installed conflicts util-linux < ('0', '2.23', None): util-linux-ng-2.17.2-13.17.amzn1.x86_64
initscripts-9.03.40-2.29.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with initscripts-9.03.38-1.22.amzn1.x86_64
1:java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-66.1.13.1.63.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-66.1.13.1.62.amzn1.x86_64
kpartx-0.4.9-72.7.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with kpartx-0.4.9-64.6.amzn1.x86_64
ksh-20120801-10.12.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with ksh-20100621-19.11.amzn1.x86_64
libblkid-2.23.2-6.21.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with libblkid-2.17.2-13.17.amzn1.x86_64
libcom_err-1.42.8-2.29.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with libcom_err-1.42.3-3.17.amzn1.x86_64
libcurl-7.36.0-2.44.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with libcurl-7.35.0-2.42.amzn1.x86_64
libgcrypt-1.5.3-1.14.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with libgcrypt-1.4.5-9.12.amzn1.x86_64
14:libpcap-1.4.0-1.20130826git2dbcaa1.10.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with 14:libpcap-1.0.0-6.20091201git117cb5.9.amzn1.x86_64
libss-1.42.8-2.29.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with libss-1.42.3-3.17.amzn1.x86_64
libtool-ltdl-2.4.2-18.4.8.2.21.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with libtool-ltdl-2.2.10-4.6.3.14.amzn1.x86_64
libudev-173-4.13.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with libudev-173-4.12.amzn1.x86_64
libuuid-2.23.2-6.21.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with libuuid-2.17.2-13.17.amzn1.x86_64
libxml2-2.9.1-1.1.29.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with libxml2-2.9.1-1.1.28.amzn1.x86_64
libxslt-1.1.28-3.8.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with libxslt-1.1.26-2.7.amzn1.x86_64
libyaml-0.1.6-1.6.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with libyaml-0.1.4-6.5.amzn1.x86_64
mdadm-3.2.6-7.29.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with mdadm-3.2.5-4.23.amzn1.x86_64
mysql-5.5-1.6.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with mysql-5.5-1.3.amzn1.noarch
mysql-server-5.5-1.6.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with mysql-server-5.5-1.3.amzn1.noarch
mysql55-5.5.36-1.44.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with mysql55-5.5.34-1.40.amzn1.x86_64
mysql55-common-5.5.36-1.44.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with mysql55-common-5.5.34-1.40.amzn1.x86_64
mysql55-libs-5.5.36-1.44.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with mysql55-libs-5.5.34-1.40.amzn1.x86_64
mysql55-server-5.5.36-1.44.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with mysql55-server-5.5.34-1.40.amzn1.x86_64
nss-util-3.15.3-1.19.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with nss-util-3.15.3-1.18.amzn1.x86_64
numactl-2.0.7-8.11.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with numactl-2.0.7-6.10.amzn1.x86_64
1:openssl-1.0.1g-1.69.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:openssl-1.0.1e-4.55.amzn1.x86_64
pam-1.1.8-1.25.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with pam-1.1.1-13.20.amzn1.x86_64
4:perl-5.16.3-280.36.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with 4:perl-5.10.1-136.21.amzn1.x86_64
perl-DBD-MySQL-4.023-2.16.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with perl-DBD-MySQL-4.020-2.8.amzn1.x86_64
perl-DBI-1.627-1.7.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with perl-DBI-1.609-4.4.amzn1.x86_64
1:perl-Digest-SHA-5.85-1.4.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:perl-Digest-SHA-5.47-136.21.amzn1.x86_64
perl-Digest-SHA1-2.13-7.6.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with perl-Digest-SHA1-2.12-2.4.amzn1.x86_64
perl-Encode-Locale-1.03-4.7.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with perl-Encode-Locale-1.02-3.1.amzn1.noarch
perl-HTML-Tagset-3.20-14.6.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with perl-HTML-Tagset-3.20-4.4.amzn1.noarch
perl-LWP-MediaTypes-6.02-1.8.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with perl-LWP-MediaTypes-6.01-3.3.amzn1.noarch
1:perl-Module-Pluggable-4.8-1.2.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with 1:perl-Module-Pluggable-3.90-136.21.amzn1.x86_64
perl-Net-LibIDN-0.12-13.5.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with perl-Net-LibIDN-0.12-3.2.amzn1.x86_64
1:perl-Pod-Escapes-1.04-280.36.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with 1:perl-Pod-Escapes-1.04-136.21.amzn1.x86_64
1:perl-Pod-Simple-3.28-3.5.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with 1:perl-Pod-Simple-3.13-136.21.amzn1.x86_64
1:perl-TimeDate-2.30-1.6.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with 1:perl-TimeDate-1.16-11.1.4.amzn1.noarch
perl-URI-1.60-8.7.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with perl-URI-1.40-2.5.amzn1.noarch
perl-XML-NamespaceSupport-1.11-9.7.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with perl-XML-NamespaceSupport-1.10-3.5.amzn1.noarch
4:perl-libs-5.16.3-280.36.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with 4:perl-libs-5.10.1-136.21.amzn1.x86_64
perl-podlators-2.5.1-2.7.amzn1.noarch has installed conflicts perl < ('4', '5.16.1', '234'): 4:perl-5.10.1-136.21.amzn1.x86_64
3:perl-version-0.99.02-2.5.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with 3:perl-version-0.77-136.21.amzn1.x86_64
psmisc-22.20-6.11.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with psmisc-22.6-15.8.amzn1.x86_64
pyliblzma-0.5.3-3.6.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with pyliblzma-0.5.3-3.4.amzn1.x86_64
python26-2.6.9-1.46.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with python26-2.6.9-1.43.amzn1.x86_64
python26-libs-2.6.9-1.46.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with python26-libs-2.6.9-1.43.amzn1.x86_64
readline-6.2-6.13.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with readline-6.0-4.12.amzn1.x86_64
rpm-4.11.2-2.54.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with rpm-4.11.1-3.49.amzn1.x86_64
rpm-build-libs-4.11.2-2.54.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with rpm-build-libs-4.11.1-3.49.amzn1.x86_64
rpm-libs-4.11.2-2.54.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with rpm-libs-4.11.1-3.49.amzn1.x86_64
rpm-python-4.11.2-2.54.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with rpm-python-4.11.1-3.49.amzn1.x86_64
rsyslog-5.8.10-8.25.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with rsyslog-5.8.10-7.24.amzn1.x86_64
sqlite-3.7.17-1.9.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with sqlite-3.6.20-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
system-release-2014.03-2.0.noarch is a duplicate with system-release-2013.09-1.0.noarch
sysvinit-2.87-5.dsf.14.amzn1.x86_64 has installed conflicts util-linux < ('0', '2.23.2', None): util-linux-ng-2.17.2-13.17.amzn1.x86_64
sysvinit-2.87-5.dsf.14.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with sysvinit-2.87-4.dsf.10.amzn1.x86_64
tcp_wrappers-7.6-75.11.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with tcp_wrappers-7.6-57.9.amzn1.x86_64
tcp_wrappers-libs-7.6-75.11.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with tcp_wrappers-libs-7.6-57.9.amzn1.x86_64
tzdata-2013i-2.23.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with tzdata-2013c-2.18.amzn1.noarch
tzdata-java-2013i-2.23.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with tzdata-java-2013c-2.18.amzn1.noarch
udev-173-4.13.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with udev-173-4.12.amzn1.x86_64
upstart-0.6.5-13.3.13.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with upstart-0.6.5-12.10.amzn1.x86_64
util-linux-2.23.2-6.21.amzn1.x86_64 has installed conflicts coreutils < ('0', '8.20', None): coreutils-8.4-31.20.amzn1.x86_64
util-linux-2.23.2-6.21.amzn1.x86_64 has installed conflicts sysvinit < ('0', '2.87', '5'): upstart-0.6.5-12.10.amzn1.x86_64, sysvinit-2.87-4.dsf.10.amzn1.x86_64
2:vim-common-7.4.027-2.28.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with 2:vim-common-7.2.411-1.8.17.amzn1.x86_64
2:vim-minimal-7.4.027-2.28.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with 2:vim-minimal-7.2.411-1.8.17.amzn1.x86_64
xz-5.1.2-5alpha.10.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with xz-4.999.9-0.3.beta.20091007git.8.amzn1.x86_64
xz-libs-5.1.2-5alpha.10.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with xz-libs-4.999.9-0.3.beta.20091007git.8.amzn1.x86_64
xz-lzma-compat-5.1.2-5alpha.10.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with xz-lzma-compat-4.999.9-0.3.beta.20091007git.8.amzn1.x86_64
yum-3.4.3-137.51.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with yum-3.4.3-111.46.amzn1.noarch
yum-plugin-priorities-1.1.31-18.17.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with yum-plugin-priorities-1.1.31-17.16.amzn1.noarch
yum-plugin-upgrade-helper-1.1.31-18.17.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with yum-plugin-upgrade-helper-1.1.31-17.16.amzn1.noarch
```

Comment: What's the output of `yum repolist`?

Comment: @JoelDavis yum repolist
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
repo id                               repo name                           status
!amzn-main/latest                     amzn-main-Base                      4,801
!amzn-updates/latest                  amzn-updates-Base                   1,361
repolist: 6,162

Answer (score 0):

You should solve that by opening a support ticket with Amazon or whoever provides those packages. You can't "fix" file conflicts, those are packaging issues.

Answer (score 0):

instructions to determine what packages [rpm's] were installed from which repository from the this

[List all RPM packages installed from repo "X"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22560/list-all-rpm-packages-installed-from-repo-x)

Based on seeing **amzn1** leads me to believe you have an Amazon Web Service (AWS) repo and you installed a bunch of stuff `*amzn1.x86_64` from there.

CentOS recently updated from 7.6 to 7.7, and likely the AWS repo is conflicting with the CentOS 7.7 stuff.

I am not familiar with AWS and what they have to offer for centos, but they are the problem here.  A solution is to uninstall everything `amzn` related and disable their repo, along with any other repo's other than the CentOS base repositories and EPEL, this would be the typical procedure when something like this happens... revert all the way back to operating system base repositories until everything works properly from the base repository.  Not surprising since some other repo's for various packages conflicted with the centos 7.7 update.